# What's the difference between いつだって and いつでも?

Tags: words, word-choice

Pretty simple, like the title says, what's the difference between いつだって and いつでも?  I can tell there's a little difference, but it's so very difficult for me to pin down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「いつだって」 is a more casual way of saying 「いつでも」 and it has a little emphasis on its meaning compared to 「いつでも」. You'll hardly see 「だって」 being used in newspaper articles compared to 「でも」.

**だって**　source: デジタル大辞泉 (http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/137401/m0u/)

> ［係助］《断定の助動詞「だ」に係助詞「とて」の付いた「だとて」の音変化という》名詞・副詞、一部の助詞に付く。「でも」に似るが、語調がより強い。

Also this might be of your interest: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/17174/m0u/

Comment: Would you say: "いつだってうちに来てください"？

Comment: You can say it. It may sound　slightly awkward though depending on the situation. I would add `ね` at the end like 「いつだってうちに来てくださいね」 or 「いつだってうちに来てね」. Without `ね`, 「下さい」 is polite but feels a bit formal by itself. `ね` creates a friendly effect so it corresponds to `だって`.